# ASP - Minute into Hours

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, datediff

I am calculating hours from mins.

```
 <% hrs =(DateDiff("N", cdate(m1), CDate(m2)  ))/60 %> .
```

it's not giving expected output.

I need this hrs to generate salary 
so time hrs should like this  7.25 , 7.50, 7.75 and on ...   not 7.23 or 7.28, 7.30
some time its gives 7.833333333333

Please help

Comment: Your specification is very weak.  Do you mean you only want hr values generated in 15 minute increments?  If so what is the rounding policy needed?  E.g do you want to round down to the nearest whole quater of an hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is what you really want is this:-

```
 Dim hrs
 hrs = Int(DateDiff("N", CDate(m1), CDate(m2)) / 15) / 4
```

This is on the basis that you only pay salary against time worked measured in quarter an hour increments.

Answer (score 1):

Anthony's solution is awesome but it rounds down. If you want to round up over 7 minutes to the nearest 15 minutes then use the following:

```
Const csRoundUp = 7
Dim Minutes
Dim hrs

Minutes = Int(DateDiff("N", CDate(Date1), CDate(Date2)) Mod 60)
if Minutes > csRoundUp  then
  hrs = (Int(DateDiff("N", CDate(Date1), CDate(Date2)) / 15)+1) / 4
else
  hrs = Int(DateDiff("N", CDate(Date1), CDate(Date2)) / 15) / 4
end if
```

Of course you can change the value of csRoundUp to anything you deem appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
100Minutes = 100 * 60Minutes \ 60
```

to calculate centi-minutes from 'normal' minutes. Demo:

```
  Dim dtStart : dtStart = #11/5/2011 08:00:00#
  Dim aTests  : aTests  = Array( _
        0, 1, 6, 15, 30, 45, 59, 60, 90 _
  )
  Dim nAddMins
  For Each nAddMins In aTests
      Dim dtStop : dtStop = DateAdd( "n", 7 * 60 + nAddMins, dtStart )
      Dim dtDiff : dtDiff = CDate( dtStop - dtStart )
      Dim nHours : nHours = Hour(   dtDiff )
      Dim nMins  : nMins  = Minute( dtDiff )
      If nAddMins Mod 60 <> nMins Then
         Err.Raise vbObjectError + 4711, "CentiMinute", nAddMins & " <> " & nMins
      End If
      Dim nCMins : nCMins = 100 * nMins \ 60
      WScript.Echo dtStart, dtStop _
        , Right( 1000 + nAddMins, 3 ) _
        , Right(  100 + nHours  , 2 ) & ":" & Right(  100 + nMins   , 2 ) _
        , Right(  100 + nHours  , 2 ) & "." & Right(  100 + nCMins  , 2 )
  Next
```

Output (German locale):

```
=========================================================
05.11.2011 08:00:00 05.11.2011 15:00:00 000 07:00 07.00
05.11.2011 08:00:00 05.11.2011 15:01:00 001 07:01 07.01
05.11.2011 08:00:00 05.11.2011 15:06:00 006 07:06 07.10
05.11.2011 08:00:00 05.11.2011 15:15:00 015 07:15 07.25
05.11.2011 08:00:00 05.11.2011 15:30:00 030 07:30 07.50
05.11.2011 08:00:00 05.11.2011 15:45:00 045 07:45 07.75
05.11.2011 08:00:00 05.11.2011 15:59:00 059 07:59 07.98
05.11.2011 08:00:00 05.11.2011 16:00:00 060 08:00 08.00
05.11.2011 08:00:00 05.11.2011 16:30:00 090 08:30 08.50
=========================================================
```